Uncaught ReferenceError: handleRegistration is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
I have created and deployed a smart contract for IP management using truffle. I have created a frontend to interact with this deployed contract.
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Intellectual Property Management</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Intellectual Property Management</h1>
    <!-- IP Registration Form -->
    <div id="ipRegistrationForm">
        <h2>Register Intellectual Property</h2>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required><br>
        <label for="description">Description:</label>
        <textarea id="description" name="description" required></textarea><br>
        <button onclick="registerIP()" > Register IP </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Ownership Transfer Form -->
    <div id="ownershipTransferForm">
        <h2>Transfer Ownership</h2>
        <label for="ipId">IP ID:</label>
        <input type="number" id="ipId" name="ipId" required><br>
        <label for="newOwner">New Owner:</label>
        <input type="text" id="newOwner" name="newOwner" required><br>
        <button onclick="transferOwnership()">Transfer Ownership</button>
    </div>

    <!-- IP Record Lookup Form -->
    <div id="ipRecordLookupForm">
        <h2>Lookup IP Record</h2>
        <label for="lookupIpId">IP ID:</label>
        <input type="number" id="lookupIpId" name="lookupIpId" required><br>
        <button onclick="getIPRecord()">Lookup IP Record</button>
    </div>


</body>

Above is the HTML code. When I give input for registerIP and click the button is gives the error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: **handleRegistration is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:22:48) onclick @ index.html:22**

Here’s the Javascript code where the function is defined:
const contractAddress = '0x9A0D1854304e7e3509168a7B2d5cFFAC70799230'; 
    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);

    console.log('The contract: ', contract);

    async function registerIP() {
    const name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    const description = document.getElementById('description').value;
    try {
        // Call smart contract method to register IP
        const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
        console.log('Available accounts:', accounts); // Log the accounts array
        await contract.methods.registerIP(name, description).send({ from: accounts[0] });
        alert('IP Registered successfully!');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error registering IP:', error);
        alert('Failed to register IP. Please try again.');
    }
}

console.log('The contract: ', contract); logs the contract successfully.

Are you calling some handleRegistration() function at line 22 of your HTML? What’s its definition look like?
